Cannot understand why there is a case change using платить
On checking in WordHippo.com, I see that 'I pay the boy' is translated as 'я плачу мальчику'(the dative of 'boy', as I would expect); and 'I pay this boy' is 'я плачу етога мальчика'(the genitive of 'this boy'). Is it actually correct to change the case of the indirect object simply by adding a demonstrative pronoun in the sentence - or is WordHippo wrong and generally unreliable?

Я плачу́ этому мальчику? Я плачу́ за этого мальчика? Я пла́чу по этому мальчику? WordHippo doesn't sound right.

Firstly, it's not етога. The word you are referring to there is этого. But, no, there is not a shift to the accusative simply because there is a demonstrative. It would be этому мальчику.
I think it makes more sense with a direct object too (+A+D, in other words) or with за to explain what you're paying for. Я плачу деньги этому мальчику. Я плачу (этому) мальчику за его услуги. [I'm not sure the English demonstrative should always be replicated in the Russian.]
Google Translate produces the correct translation, but these machine translations are never likely to always be correct. Yandex also has a translator.
